# Scala amazon S3 file upload show error not found

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the playframework 2.4.6 and trying to upload a file to my S3 bucket but I get an error on compilation: Not Found value s3. I am basically trying to copy this tutorial https://github.com/Kaliber/play-s3 and also this post which is similar
[Play! Upload file and save to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679216/play-upload-file-and-save-to-aws-s3) . My information is as follow:

**Build.SBT**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "net.kaliber" %% "play-s3" % "7.0.1",
   "net.kaliber" %% "play-s3" % "7.0.2"

)
```

**Application.conf**

```
aws.accessKeyId="akey"
aws.secretKey="skey"
```

then my controller

```
  def upload=  Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) {implicit request =>
    request.body.file("file").map { file =>
     // implicit val credential = AwsCredentials.fromConfiguration
      val byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.ref.file.getPath))

      val bucket = S3("myBuckets")
    val result = bucket + BucketFile(file.filename, file.contentType.get, byteArray, None, None)
      result.map { unit =>
        Ok("File uploaded")
      }.getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
          "error" -> "Missing file"
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting the error on **val bucket = S3("myBuckets")** as stated before it says Not found value S3 and the build crashes. I do not know if I could be missing an import as my IDE does not point it out ... This is my imports for the controller:

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, JsValue}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.mvc.Result
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import java.io.File
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing:

```
fly.play.s3._
```

Or if you want to be specific:

```
fly.play.s3.S3
```